# What are the different types of pencils used to make pencil drawing?

Tags: drawing, pencils

Although I am not a trained artist, I have heard about different types of pencils for making a pencil drawing.I do not know much about it and also why it so( HB pencils).I like to know more about it as I want to make much better drawings.

Answer (score 2):

There are H ( hard) grades ; H to 6H , HB, and B (soft) types; B to 4B (?). The B grades get about as soft as using charcoal; The hard types can cut some papers. I expect there is much more specific info on the internet.